# LMDB maximum size of the database for windows

Tags: linux, windows, lmdb

When I set the maximum db size to be, for example, 5G, on windows the final db file size will become 5G even I only insert one small piece of data. But on linux it works fine, the final db size is related with how many data I insert into.

Here's the api I used to set maximum db size

`rc = ::mdb_env_set_mapsize(env, 5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);`

Same for Windows and linux. Do I need to do something different for windows?

Answer (score 5):

That's how memory-mapped files work on Windows - if you want a map of size xxGB, Windows requires the file to be of size xxGB. Windows grows the file itself if the file was originally smaller than the specified size; there is no way around this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

NTFS can support sparse files, but in testing we found that Windows sparse file support is significantly slower than normal files, so LMDB doesn't use it.

Comment: So what would be the recommended way to use lmdb on windows when I don't know how much data there will be?

Comment: This entire question is now obsolete, as of ITS#8324 http://www.openldap.org/its/index.cgi/Software%20Enhancements?id=8324

It turns out that using the underlying NT API instead of WIN32 API, mapped files can be grown incrementally. So the original LMDB advice now applies - use as large a mapsize as possible, initially, and forget about it.

Comment: @hyc: can you please help here( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720718/values-that-can-be-stored-in-lmdb )